# Full text search of values with a special character (') produces unexpected results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm having a problem with MySQL full text search. I have a `users` table that has a single column, `username`.

The problem appears when I'm trying to search for a user with a special character (`'`) in its name. Let's say the name is `Dan v׳ila`, when searching for `"dan"` alone it finds the result but as soon as I'm searching for `"dan v"` it won't show the name with the `'` in it.

Examples of queries follow:

Returns the result:

```
Select * from uses
Match(username) against('+dan*' in boolean mode)
```

Doesn't return the result:

```
Select * from users 
Match(username) against ('+dan* +v*' in boolean mode)
```

It is worth noting that names without `'` are showing in both cases.

Comment: Did you change [innodb_ft_min_token_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size)/[ft_min_word_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) to 1 to enable search for such short words? "׳" is not apostrophe as it seems (google gives me "hebrew punctuation geresh") so MySQL probably sees that as 3 words ("Dan", "v", "ila") and "v" is too short to be indexed.

Comment: Im not in the office so i'll update but the database is in hebrew so it might be it. I still dont get why mysql considers it as widespace, and it wont be terrible on the performance side to make it search for 1 letter words? Thank you very much

Comment: FULLTEXT is not that cognizant of apostrophes inside "words".

Comment: [The MySQL FULLTEXT implementation regards any sequence of true word characters (letters, digits, and underscores) as a word. That sequence may also contain apostrophes (“'”), but not more than one in a row.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) - only "ascii" apostrophe seems to be considered for this. As for performance - how much will "word-count" grow if you consider single-letter words for search? The index wil grow but if it is some sort of tree then the performance drawback might not be so bad.

Comment: Its not an apostrophe, its a hebrew geresh. I'll try changing the parameter and update

Comment: I changed the variable and it didnt change anything. Do i have to rebuild the index or something like that?

Comment: @user69153 yes, you have to change the right variable (MyISAM/InnoDB or preferably both to keep it consistent) and then rebuild the index - remember to change the variable in config too so it stays right after server restart.